# how to pass parameters to joomla module loaded from article

Tags: joomla, parameters, module

I had previously added Joomla modules from within Joomla articles  this way : `{loadmodule mod_name}` but this time I need to pass parameters from it.

How can I pass parameters from within the article to a Joomla module?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? the parameters are in the backend/module manager, not the article

Comment: yeah they are passed from backend but I was wonder if there is a way to pass them from within the article ...I had previously seen a plugin mod_refresh when we {refesh 600}, we can pass 600 ms to the plugin, so I was wondering if there is a similair way we can pass it to a module and if so how to retrieve the data in the parameters...

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to modify or clone the Joomla plugin `loadmodule` because it doesn't handle parameters other than just a module name.  It's not particularly difficult to do if you're proficient in PHP (assuming you don't mind getting your hands dirty with a little bit of Regex work) but I'd suggest cloning it and using it this way:

1. Copy folder `\plugins\content\loadmodule` to `\plugins\content\Myloadmodule` (and all it's files)
2. Within the *new* folder, rename `loadmodule.php` and `loadmodule.xml` to `myloadmodule.php` and `myloadmodule.xml`.  *These* are the files you'll do all the work on.
3. In both files, replace occurrences of `loadmodule` with `myloadmodule`, (Case ***sensitive***)
4. In `myloadmodule.php`, start at around line 36 with the Regex that strips out what is in the `{loadposition xxx}` being processed. You'll need to tinker with this Regex to get the parameters that you want to supply when using `{myloadmoduel blah-blah-blah}` in your article.
5. Find the database entry in your table '_extensions' for `loadposition` and create and identical record for `myloadposition`.  (Unless you want to write and installer)
6. Finally, you'll need to render the modules with your new parameters - I can't begin to help there because I don't know what modules, or parameter work you'll be doing, but this [renderModule](http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/renderModule) documentation will be of assistance.
  7.

I think I've covered it all, but this should be enough to get most of it done for you.  When you're done, use `{myloadposition ...}` instead of `{loadposition ...}`.

Comment: Also, see my question about the regex when I was first figuring it out at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675691/preg-match-all-with-space-and-comma-delimiters/11675712#11675712

Answer (score 2):

I will give more details about the previous answer, to be able to pass parameters to a module with a tag as {loadmodule mod_name,param}
The solution given by GDP works fine: it's easy and quick to rewrite a content plugin (e.g. myloadmodule), following the steps 1 to 5 in the previous answer.
The problem, for me, comes with the steps 6: how to put parameters into the module, and ohow to retrieve de parameters within the module.

Step 7 : how to give parameters to the "render" of a module

In the plugin created (base on the loadmodule), you have to find the lines with the following code :

```
echo $renderer->render($module, $params);
```

Before this line, you can put parameters into the $params parameter, but "render" of the module retrieves only params with the key 'params', using a json format.
So, to pass parameters to the render function, you can do something like that :

```
$param = array('param_name' => 'value');  // param_name = value
$params = array('params' => json_encode($param)); // 'params' (String) should be decoded by the render of the module
echo $renderer->render($module, $params);
```

Step 8 : How to retrieve the parameter within the module

In the helper of your module, you can retrieve the parameter with $params variable :

```
$value = $params->get('param_name');
```

To understand a helper, read this tutorial : [http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3:Creating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.3%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module)

Answer (score 0):

I googled the same issue and found your question. I know its old but my find may help someone else. There are now plugins that allow embedding modules and allowing you to pass parameters to it. My choice is [Module Plant](http://www.j-plant.com/free-extensions/module-plant.html).

Comment: The link in your answer is outdated and there is also no Module Plant extension

Comment: Thank you @tung, for pointing out that a 5-year-old answer is no more applicable :) 
Even I would have checked the answer's date, as there have been several updates to the core of Joomla! since 2014.